# Plugin not found

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I'm very new to the JS ecosystem so please excuse some foolish mistakes I make. :-)

I'm trying to use Yeoman to generate an AngularJS application. I did that but on doing 'grunt serve' I get the error that:

```
Running "serve" task

jit-grunt: Plugin for the "clean" task not found.
If you have installed the plugin already, please setting the static mapping.
See https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings

Warning: Task "clean:server" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Which plugin am I missing now and how do I install it?

=== Update ===

After installing grunt-clean as suggested, the new error is:

```
Running "serve" task
Loading "clean.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: grunt.registerHelper is not a function

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
Warning: grunt.helper is not a function Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please run `npm install`
as this will install all the dependencies defined in package.json

Comment: Thank you! It worked but I had to use `--force` after I got this error: `Warning: Error: Cannot find where you keep your Bower packages. Use --force to continue.` Any idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: Can you please also help with the error I mentioned in my comment? :-)

Comment: for this please run "bower install"

Comment: Thanks a lot for rescuing me! :-)

Comment: Awesome, all the best :)